# Как использовать пару в качестве шаблона с переменным количеством аргументов?

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++, c++17, метапрограммирование

Хоче передать в функцию переменное число пар enum/значение, как это сделать?
Пробовал так

```
template<typename EnumT, typename CharT, std::pair<EnumT, CharT> KeyValueT>
constexpr auto makeStringsMap(KeyValueT... kv)
{

}
```

и так

```
template<typename... KeyValueT>
constexpr auto makeStringsMap(KeyValueT... kv)
{
    static_assert(std::is_enum_v<decltype(std::get<0>(kv))>);
}
```

в обоих случаях компилятор ргуается

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Подход с ассертом - приводит к ошибке компиляции, внутри функции, в случае неправильного использования.

```
template<typename... T1, typename ... T2>
constexpr auto makeStringsMap(std::pair<T1,T2>... kv)
{
    static_assert(  (std::is_enum_v<T1> && ... ) );
}
```

Другой вариант:

```
template<typename T>
concept IsEnum=std::is_enum_v<T>;

template< IsEnum... T1, typename ... T2>
constexpr auto makeStringsMap(std::pair<T1,T2>... kv)
{
    return 1;
}
```

проверка работы:

```
enum ABC {a,b,c};
auto test = makeStringsMap( std::make_pair(a,1.2), std::make_pair(a,"foo")  );
```